# Current flowing inside voltage source or battery

Tags: voltage-source

Current is the flow of charges (many say electrons).

Do these charges flow just between the terminals of the source/battery (terminal to terminal) ?

Or

These charges flow through/inside the source/battery as well?

What i know is that the positive terminal is the lack of electrons as compared to the negative terminal which is the excess of electron.

Current flows when electrons flow from the negative terminal of the battery to the positive terminal of the battery/source?

My question is what happens when the electrons reach from the negative terminal to the positive terminal? Are electrons then "absorbed" by the positive charges or they continue to flow through the source/battery to move in cycles?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Current is the flow of charges (many say electrons).

It's electrons in metals, but can be any other charge carriers in other media. In batteries, the charge carriers are positive and negative ions.

When an electron arrives from the external circuit at the positive terminal and heads off into the battery, it will either release a negative ion into the electrolyte solution, or turn a positive ion arriving from the solution into a neutral species. When it neutralises a positive ion, it's getting 'absorbed by the positive charges', but of course those charges have traveled across the electrolyte. In the event of sending a negative ion off, you could see that as the electron 'hitching a ride' across the battery. Different battery chemistries may employ all of one, the other, or both polarities of ions.

Comment: So overall it seems that the charges cross the battery to move in cycles in the circuit? @NEIL_UK

Comment: @Alex Yes, all circuits are closed, one way or another.

Comment: What about the ac generator shown in the figure.

Comment: Just an interesting blurb about how the net speed of carriers in a metal under the influence of a field is about the speed of molasses: [This page about since misconceptions](http://amasci.com/miscon/eleca.html#light) has been around since the 90's and is great.

Comment: @Alex `What about the ac generator shown in the figure.` Yes, all circuits are closed, one way or another.

Comment: Thanks alot @alanwaring for the link. It is very useful.

Answer (score 0):

In a simple circuit, the actual path of electric current is through the battery. Some books imply (or even state outright) that whenever a battery is connected in a complete circuit, the charges only flow in the wires. They say that one battery plate is the source of electrons, the other plate collects "used" electrons, and no charges flow in the chemicals between the battery plates. This is wrong. These books often contain a diagram of a battery, wires, and a light bulb. The diagram shows the current in the wires, but charges aren't shown going through the battery. This is wrong. The electrolyte is a conductor. There is a large current flowing between the battery plates.
In any simple electric circuit, the path of the electric current is a complete circle. It's like a drive belt, and it has no starting point. It goes through all parts of the circuit including the battery, and including the battery's liquid electrolyte. Between the plates of any battery we find a highly conductive liquid. Sometimes its an acid (as with car batteries.) Sometimes it's alkaline, and sometimes it's salt water. (But how can a battery even work, if the plates are connected together with conductive fluid?